# How do WordPress themes work in relation to content?

Tags: themes, content

Premise: I have experience with WordPress only from an admin's perspective point, not custom themes, so forgive the that the question is very general.

I am well aware that WordPress stores content in the mysql database.

If I install on theme that I downloaded, add content, can I (and how) retrieve such content in a different theme?

Comment: The theme retrieves the content for you. Some themes are highly customized, with the theme adding functionality, but most just apply different CSS styles and HTML markup to the exact same content. That way you can switch themes and not lose content.

Comment: A theme is 'just' a kind of shell around the content. As you already mentioned, all content is/will be stored in the db. (and therefore independent of a theme) You can have numerous themes with the same content. The layout of a theme will make the difference for how it will be presented to your users. So there is in a way not a how to do just a do :)